# Split a string into multiple columns of variable length using R

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a faster way to to the following, I need to split a column of a data.table object containing strings into separate columns. The strings are of the format "name1=value1;name2=value2;". The strings can be split into a variable number of columns in which case those values will need to be filled with NA. For example I have this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("foo"=c("name=john;id=1234;last=smith", "name=greg;id=5678", "last=picard", "last=jones;number=1234567890"))
```

I would want this:

`name    id    last     number
john    1234  smith    NA
greg    5678  NA       NA
NA      NA    picard   NA
NA      NA    jones    1234567890`

This will work but it is slow given the amount of data to parse and I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(dt$foo), ";|=")
a <- function(x){
     name <- x[seq(1, length(x), 2)]
     value <- x[seq(2, length(x), 2)]
     tmp <- transpose(as.data.table(value))
     names(tmp) <- name
     return(tmp)
  }
x <- lapply(x, a)
x <- rbindlist(x, fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try:

```
# split into different fields for each row
res <- lapply(strsplit(dt$foo, ';'), function(x){
    # split the the fields into two vectors of field names and field values
    res <- tstrsplit(x, '=')
    # make a list of field values with the field names as names of the list 
    setNames(as.list(res[[2]]), res[[1]])
})

rbindlist(res, fill = T)
#    name   id   last     number
# 1: john 1234  smith         NA
# 2: greg 5678     NA         NA
# 3:   NA   NA picard         NA
# 4:   NA   NA  jones 1234567890

dplyr::bind_rows(res)

# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#    name    id   last     number
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
# 1  john  1234  smith       <NA>
# 2  greg  5678   <NA>       <NA>
# 3  <NA>  <NA> picard       <NA>
# 4  <NA>  <NA>  jones 1234567890
```

According to comment by  David Arenburg, we can improve the speed by adding `fixed = TRUE` to both `strsplit`. I did a short benchmark with this data, adding `fixed = TRUE` will increase the speed by about one fold.

```
library(microbenchmark)

dt <- dt[sample.int(nrow(dt), 100, replace = T)]

microbenchmark(
    noFix = {
        res <- lapply(strsplit(dt$foo, ';'), function(x){
            res <- tstrsplit(x, '=')
            setNames(as.list(res[[2]]), res[[1]])
        })
    },
    Fixed = {
        res <- lapply(strsplit(dt$foo, ';', fixed = TRUE), function(x){
            res <- tstrsplit(x, '=', fixed = TRUE)
            setNames(as.list(res[[2]]), res[[1]])
        })
    },
    times = 1000
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# noFix 1.921947 1.999386 2.212511 2.064997 2.218706 11.290072  1000
# Fixed 1.026753 1.088712 1.226519 1.131899 1.219558  4.490796  1000
```

Comment: Prolly want type.convert=TRUE inside tstrsplit so that `number is num not char.

Comment: @Frank, I think this doesn't work because after `tstrsplit`, the number will be in same vector with name so that it will be coerced to character. We can convert to numeric after `rbindlist` if we want.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I didn't test and underestimated how weird the OP's data was.

Comment: Thanks @mt1022, much faster! might be good to add as.character(dt$foo) depending on how the data has been read in.

Comment: If you want this to be really fast, add `fixed = TRUE` to both `strsplit` calls

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I did a simple benchmark in edit and it really fast. Could you clarify how this works? I guess it will do some unnecessary regex parsing of the fixed string pattern, but no sure and didn't find related text in manual.

Comment: It is documented really under `grep` and such. It's just does an exact match instead of running an regex engine which is much cheaper. With base functions such as `grep` and al., the speed difference could be even 10 fold. As a rule of thumb, whenever you do an exact match rather some expression, always add `fixed = TRUE`- it is more typing but usually pays off.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks very much. I found it  in 'Performance considerations' section of the manual of `grep`.

Comment: Also, a simple example could be `test <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1e5, 2, "[a-z]") ; microbenchmark::microbenchmark(grep("a", test), grep("a", test, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the speed improvement is really about 10 fold. I played with this example and found `fixed=T` works great for single character, and the improvement will reduce to ~4 fold with longer fixed patterns.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the use case, but it certainly can't perform worse. It is actually also safer if you separator is a metacharacter and you forgot.